# Windows 2008 R2 performance IPv6 traffic vs IPv4

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ip, router, ipv6

Is there reliable stats on performance of Windows server 2008 R2 with intense TCP traffic over IPv6 vs IPv4 ?

I know IPv6 header is larger but easier to process for the routers. but what about Windows? does it have adverse effect on the end-users?

Comment: So much depends on your server, nic, apps, and driver, it is difficult to imagine answering this in a helpful way

Comment: OK. is there _any information on IPv6 Windows Server implementation vs RedHat Enterprise latency-wise? With same NICs and best possible driver settings?

Comment: PS when I ask too narrow question I got it closed because its localised. Now I am asking general question still not happy... What to do??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The performance is the same, as most of the processing is offloaded to hardware in 2008 R2. Just use enterprise level cards like Intel Pro 10GBps.